# Widget don't display his content

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I'm trying to create a widget who display a bootstrap container with some content in columns.
The widget is on my list when I edit the page but when I click on it. The widget don"t display the content.

so my widget.html is just a couple line of html, one section with a container class, a div with an row class and two div with col-6 classes. And for finish some text inside it.

```
<section class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">test</div>
        <div class="col-6">test</div>
    </div>
</section>
```

And my index.js :

```
module.exports = {
    extend: 'apostrophe-widgets',
    label: 'A container bootstrap',
    addFields: [
      {
        name: 'container',
        type: 'area',        
        label: 'container',
      }
    ]
  };
```

I call it inside the home.html with that code :

```
{{
    apos.area(data.page, 'container', {
      widgets: {
        'bootstrap-container': {},
      }
    })
}}
```

And the init inside the app.js

```
'bootstrap-container': {},
```

I'm starting with apostrophe, someone know why my code doesn't work ? I probably made a mistake somewhere but i don't find it

Comment: Do you get your markup with the two Test columns?

Comment: no, but I finally resolve my problem and i forget to update my question

Comment: Can you post your answer as a follow up and mark this questions Answered? Thanks!